# Include PHP From Google File

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm using a Google Script which takes content from a google spreadsheet and makes a file.  It makes a PHP file with many queries, displaying certain things based on the webpage visited, with all of the conditions being specified in the spreadsheet.  However, I don't know how to include that PHP file into my website.

I previously used file_get_contents to get just HTML and JavaScript files into the website, but I don't know how to do this with PHP.  Any suggestions?  Right now, with this method, it shows the PHP in the HTML, but doesn't run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand this PHP file is stored in Google Drive? Because the obvious method is to store it directly on your server.

Anyway, since the file is in a remote location you face a bit of a problem. In addition, `file_get_contents()` is not the right way to include PHP code (instead use one of the functions bellow). You can either:

1. Save it as a local file programmatically & include it
2. Enable `allow_url_fopen` & `allow_url_include` in your `php.ini`. Keep in mind that it opens not a small security hole in you server.

So in option **1** you will:

```
$local_filename = 'your/local/file.php';
file_put_contents($local_filename, file_get_contents($gdrive_file_url));
require_once($local_filename); //and not file_get_contents()
```

and in option **2** you will just

```
require_once($gdrive_file_url);
```

You can replace `require_once()`<sup>[API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)</sup> with either `include()`<sup>[API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)</sup>, `require()`<sup>[API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)</sup> or `include_once()`<sup>[API](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)</sup>. See API link to each of them.

Cheers